# Polyglossia \setotherlanguage after update of TeXLive conflicts with luatextra

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, mactex, update

I am using LuaLaTeX at Mac (LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022) restricted system commands enabled).

After yesterdays update Polyglossia started to conflict with luatextra when \setotherlanguage is use (I checked only with latin). I may switch off \setotherlanguage or switch luatextra to compile the file properly but I want to use both.

Actually the file is compiled but a bunch of errors is produce.

For example:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty:41: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
^
l.41 \catcode`\^^
               A=\catcode`\%
```

Or:

```
Critical Package polyglossia Error: The language * is not loaded.
```

Any suggestions?

````
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{luainputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{polish}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatextra}

\begin{document}
Tekst w języku polskim.
\end{document}```
````

Comment: Unrelated, but why on earth are you still using luainputenc??

Comment: Add ``\catcode`\^=7 `` after loading the latin language as a work-around.

Comment: I guess luainputenc is useful for „” = opt+[ and opt+{. Am I wrong? When I % luainputenc those signs are making troubles. Maybe not in some files I have to bring it back and even switch to babel when using two languages. I guess I just don't understand lualatex+Mac+gregorio+fontenc and several languages in document. Any source I may learn it from?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it is the solution I was looking for. Thank you very much! I just needed to compile the file with gregoriotex twice.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend to separate package loading from settings.

If you do

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{luainputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatextra}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{polish}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\begin{document}
Tekst w języku polskim.
\end{document}
```

there is no error. On the other hand, `luainputenc` should be used with some option or it's useless. Also, `luatextra` is a wrapper for loading

```
fontspec luatexbase metalogo luacode fixltx2e
```

and the library `lualibs` for `luatexbase`. I don't think you really need them (surely not `fixltx2e` that just issues an annoying warning). If you need `luacode` or `metalogo` load them.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}% also loads fontspec

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{polish}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\begin{document}

Tekst w języku polskim.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comments and explanation. I deleted luainputenc and luatextra. It helped with compiling MWE but not if I work with other packages (ie. gregoriotex).

Comment: @TomaszGrabowski as I wrote add the catcode change after loading Latin. The language has a bug that emerged after a expl3 update. It will be fixed it a few days.

Answer (score 0):

As Ulrike Fisher noted in a comment above, there have been changes in `expl3`. There have also been changes to `polyglossia` (closely related to the other changes). This occurred some time in 2023. If you are using TeXlive 2023, and have everything updated, then the original code (in the question) may compile without error. I now have TeXlive 2024, and the original code does compile without error.