# Problem with latin language from polyglossia and xcolor

Tags: color, polyglossia, latin

After recent update of Tex Live 2022 engine (especially `polyglossia` package) my document is no more compiling giving a lot of errors. The root cause of these errors is probably using of `latin` language from `polyglossia` in combination with `xcolor` package.

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Compiling with  `lualatex.exe  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "document".tex`.

As the result I have a few errors (in real document there is a much more of them):

[image: error]

**BTW** With other languages (have tried a few) this problem was not observed. But the same error appears even if `latin` is used only as "otherlanguage":

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: see my comment there https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663753/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\catcode`\^=7 ` helped! Thanks!